# 301 redirect asp to aspx in webconfig - negate certain pages that have query strings

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

I Have a redirect rule in my web.config file that redirects all .asp pages to .aspx. However, there are a few url's with .asp extensions that I do not want to redirect.

These urls are displayed like this in the browser address bar.

https://www.example.com/seriesdisplay.asp?cat=DR3&class=50

I attempted to use the following rule below. It works in not redirecting the seriesdisplay.asp page itself, but any pages the contain the two query strings, it still redirects.

How can I not redirect all the seriesdisplay.asp pages that also contain query strings?

```
  <rule name="Redirect-asp-aspx-IIS-new">
    <match url="(.*?)asp$" ignoreCase="true" /> 
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/seriesdisplay\.asp$" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}x" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
  <rule name="Redirect-asp-aspx-IIS-new">
    <match url="(.*?)asp$" ignoreCase="true" /> 
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/seriesdisplay(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}x" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```